# Lots of rows (eav) vs lots of empty columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema, entity-attribute-value

I'm attempting a redesign of the database schema for a website where we have a dynamic form filled out by users based on the category they fit into.  The end result of this dynamic form is that I have 100+ columns in the database to store their answers but in any given case less than 10 will actually have a value.

I'm looking to really tighten up the database as much as possible and remove NULL values where possible and 1 solution to the above problem that I am considering is to use a EAV table to hold the answers to variable questions.

So table 1 would hold their name and a few other bits and table 2 would have a row holding the question and answer to each question with a foreign key linking to table 1.

I've done some slap dash calculations that if they were to get 1000 forms filled a day (high estimate, not impossible in the longer term) I'm looking at up to 2,600,000 rows in table 2 per year (1000 * 10 * 260 - working days).  My primary key will go up as far as 4 billion so that isn't a problem but I'm concerned that after a few years with 5 - 10 million records that performance will seriously degrade.

I'm mostly concerned with performance, as far as structure goes, EAV is very much preferable as it will allow my client to add new questions without having to interact with the database and it helps keep my database schema much tighter and I'm not concerned about how this complicates my code if it is the right data solution.

Comment: As long as they are properly indexed, large numbers of rows in a table should not be an issue. You will need a foreign key/index to link the EAV attribute values to your main form table

Comment: currently looks like this:

id,
id_entity (FK),
attribute (question code),
value,
value_large (TEXT to take strings longer than 255),
title (how the information is described back to the user),
date_added

Comment: As only 10% of the fields will be used, you might consider putting all the answers in an array and then storing them all in a single text column using `serialize()` or better still `json_encode()`. You could also consider removing all the unanswered questions before doing this so your string is nice and small. It would mean your code that uses this data from the database would need to expect and handle missing data.

Comment: In mysql, adding a column is very expensive operation, it means recreating the whole table.

Comment: @Marek, currently each user has their own database and I'm having to add a column to the schema almost weekly.  It's a total mess.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have never stored an array in a database, would such a solution be common practise?

Comment: Not sure about common, but it is used where the situation warrants it, and this seems to be one that might fit.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll do a little digging on how I would implement this.